# IE-8 - 'undefined' is null or not an object. Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've a jQuery ajax based submit button which calls below `forTime()` function during `onclick`. Inside the function i am using jstz api for getting timezone. While clicking on Clock In/Out, in IE  error is being thrown.

> 'undefined' is null or not an object. Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

But it is working fine in Chrome and Firefox. But for first time(Clock In/Out) is working in IE, but after first time error is being thrown.

Here is my code:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jstz-1.0.4.min.js"/>
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/downloads/jstz-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function forTime()
    {
        var tz = jstz.determine();
        console.log(tz.name());
        document.getElementById('admHomeForm:hiddenTimeFieldId').value = tz.name();
        console.log("System Time--> "+document.getElementById('admHomeForm:hiddenTimeFieldId').value);
        console.log(moment.tz.zone(tz.name()).abbr(new Date().getTime()));

    }
</script>

    </head>
```

Comment: why have you included two `jstz` script files? Remove one.. additionally see this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468050/ie8-respond-js-undefined-is-null-or-not-an-object

Comment: try adding this, `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=6">`

Comment: Did you try using a search engine?

Comment: script tags aren't self closing

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary Tried your way. But not working

Comment: @charlietfl All the scripts are closed

Comment: @Kukeltje Already googled about this many times..Didn't get any solution

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jstz-1.0.4.min.js"/>` isn't closed. It has no closing tag and that closing tag is not optional

Comment: Actually, it is closed. You meant to say that self closing (short tag) is not allowed on script tag.

Comment: @BalusC: yes, a script tag cannot be self closed.